# error while compiling opencv for QT

Tags: windows, opencv, compilation, cmake, qt5

i want to use `opencv` in `QT`, so i must compile it with `mingw`. When i want to compile it with `CMake 2.8.10.2` it has following error

```
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.2
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:54 (message):
      The C++ compiler "C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" is not able to
      compile a simple test program.

      It fails with the following output:

       Change Dir: C:/opencv_bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



      Run Build Command:C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe
      "cmTryCompileExec2270185098/fast"

      C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
      CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2270185098.dir\build.make
      CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2270185098.dir/build

      mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
      'C:/opencv_bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

      "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report
      C:\opencv_bin\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CMakeFiles 1

      'C:\Users\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

      operable program or batch file.

      CMakeFiles\cmTryCompileExec2270185098.dir\build.make:59: recipe for target
      'CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2270185098.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj' failed

      mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
      [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2270185098.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj] Error
      1

      mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/opencv_bin/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

      makefile:116: recipe for target 'cmTryCompileExec2270185098/fast' failed

      mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTryCompileExec2270185098/fast] Error 2





      CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      CMakeLists.txt:61 (project)


    Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

any idea?

Comment: Do you have the file "C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/g++.exe" ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a newer version but in my case you should try in the folder QtSDK/minGW/bin instead of Qt folder.

Comment: newer version if Cmake or  OpenCV?

Comment: Please explain more about QtSDK/minGW/bin

Comment: try the first options on the download page:
http://qt-project.org/downloads
for example: http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.0/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.0-x86-offline.run