# Can't Make Opencv for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

I've been following the guide posted here https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows for setting up opencv for Qt.
Everything works as it should until the mingw32-make command where the compile fails with the same error:

Scanning dependencies of target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[ 31%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx.obj
[ 31%] Linking CXX static library ....\lib\libopencv_core_pch_dephelp.a
[ 31%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
Scanning dependencies of target pch_Generate_opencv_core
mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'lib/libopencv_core_pch_dephelp.a', needed by 'modules/core/precomp.hpp.gch/opencv_core_Release.gch'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1688: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/pch_Generate_opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:161: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

This issue has been logged before here [error while compiling opencv for QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111479/error-while-compiling-opencv-for-qt)
and here
[Error when compiling OpenCV for Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171280/error-when-compiling-opencv-for-qt)
but so far no definitive solution has been reported.
My OS is Windows 10 pro and I've been using the MinGW Makefiles generator with gcc and g++. Qt version is 5.9.1 and I've had the same issues with both opencv 3.3.0 and 3.2.0.

Appreciate any help you can offer this newbie.

Comment: Without your environment that is a guess game but from OpenCV side what means to be integrated with Qt is WITH_QT=ON, like: http://answers.opencv.org/question/22816/how-to-set-the-path-to-qt5-in-cmake/

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes the WITH_QT=ON is required and so is the WITH_OPENGL=ON according to Qt's documentation. It also recommends disabling precompiled headers for some linking problems, though no variation on these seems to work.

Comment: Try with MS C++ compiler (free now) I guess, not even sure if that was ever tested with mingw. I built that on Mac and Linux with no problem.

Comment: Thanks, for whatever reason I was able get a clean compile using VS 14 2015 without the precompiled headers. Appreciate the recommendation!